# Can't make a proper gradient fade effect

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to make a gradient overlay in my images, that makes this effect:

[image]

As you can see, gradient will be darker at the bottom, BUT, the top WONT be affected by the darkness.

I've tried this:

```
@include linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1));
```

But this will make a whitish effect at the top. I want the gradient to darken only the bottom part of the image, and DON'T do anything to the upper part of the image.

Has anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following CSS, http://jsfiddle.net/3sxd82nf/5/

```
    <div id="test">x</div>
    <div id="gradient"></div>



    #test {
        position:absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url('http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/198321/50s-diner-chick-squares.jpg');

    }
#gradient {
     position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;   

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */



}
```

Comment: This will darken a bit all of the image also, which I need to be not darkened

Comment: Ok no problem you can change the gradient range, just one sec I will edit my solution :-)

Comment: @Gibson I have edited my question, please use css with all prefix, similarly at what I have provided, so you are pretty sure the gradient will render correctly in the majority of browsers.

Comment: Thanks Gibbok, much nicer. I'm using Bourbon so I don't need to worry about prefixes, it uses them automatically :=) . Thanks!